# Why is my asp.net report viewer showing no data found for no obvious specific reason?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I followed this tutorial https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Charts-to-ASPNet-ReportViewer-Control-Display-Pie-Chart-in-RDLC-Report-in-ASPNet.aspx  and this tutorial https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15597/using-the-asp-net-2-0-reportviewer-in-local-mode

Needless to say that both works very well.

The problem is that after five minutes of interaction with my wapplication, when I go back to the webforms containing the reports I get :

> No data available

This happens for both reports based on those tutorial 
**it's just as if my datasets get unplugged after 5 min**
The solution I have found so far is to RECREATE the whole report to make it work another 5 to 10 minutes. I have no idea how this can happen. Below is the code I am using :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/report1.rdlc");
                DataSetArticle Myds = GetData();
                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("dsReport", Myds .Tables[0]);
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            }
        }

        protected DataSetArticle GetData()
        {
            string query = "select cola, colb from mytable";
            string conString = "myconnection string";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;

                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataSetArticle dsMe = new DataSet1())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dsMe, "DataTable1");
                        return dsMe;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is an image of the error [image]

Image of the debugger

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @qxg Hmm I'm doing it right now.....breakpoint

Comment: @qxg  Hmm that's weird. When I fire the debugger it shows a `cmd` window and just shuts down after that. The webform is never loaded. So I guess I cant use breaklpoints to explore it

Comment: put breakpoint in line `  if (!IsPostBack)` and check what is going on.

Comment: @P.K. The line `sda.Fill(dsMe, "DataTable1");` seems to not be filling neither the `dsMe` nor the `DataTable1`. I see `count = 0` or ` When `GetData` returns, `dsArticlesVentes.Tables[0]` shows `count = 0` for the `rows` property and `result view` .... In short `GetData` is returning an empty datatable. (The structure of the datatable is correct though)  See the debugger image above in my OP

Comment: @qxg Please see the comment above and the debugger image in my OP

Comment: `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString)` is not meaning that the connection is opened. Use   `conn.Open();` Full example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/9197xfyw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @P.K. Same result.  Is it possible `SqlDataAdapter` is failing ?

Comment: Check if connection is opened in adapter too.   Check if you have access to sql server with your credentials. Check if select command is properly built ie. it uses proper column names.

Comment: @P.K.  Everything is fine. I have no idea what s going on. The same code worked once and the just stopped without me changing any settings

Comment: @P.K. My bad.... Everything was fine BUTthe table I was querying was empty...So obviously I got not result back from it....Thank you P.K

Comment: So you can mark my answers as useful :)